# How to send logs from serilog file into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

I'm using ELK stack for saving and monitoring logs. But I have a wpf app that is working on a remote pc and writing logs to the txt file using serilog. Once an error occured i want this file to be sent to the API. After this file is received i want all the logs from this file to be sent to elastic. I know that i can save this file to a folder and then send this logs to elastic using filebeat. But is there any way to do this without saving this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've asked this question on github and got the answer that there is no default implementation for this and there are two ways to send file logs to elastic: saving file and read logs with filebeat and use custom api that parses logs and write this logs right  from api. this is the github answer https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/211